# Moving node by tilting device in Spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, accelerometer, core-motion

Good morning. I have a problem with Spritekit and the Accelerometer of an iPhone. I want to move a Node by tilting the device left or right in portrait mode. Exactly like in the Doodle Jump way.

Now i have this code:

```
import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

//Then at the implementation:


_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; if ([_motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES) {

[_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error) { 

 float destX, destY; float currentX = _node.position.x; float currentY = _node.position.y; BOOL shouldMove = NO;

 if(data.acceleration.x < -0.25) {
            destX = currentX + (data.acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
            destY = currentY;
            shouldMove = YES; }

        else if (data.acceleration.x > 0.25) {
            destX = currentX + (data.acceleration.x * kPlayerSpeed);
            destY = currentY;
            shouldMove = YES;
            }

        if((destX < 0)||(destX > self.frame.size.width)){shouldMove = NO;}
        if(shouldMove) {
            SKAction *action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(destX, destY) duration:0.2];
            action.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;

            [_node runAction:action];
        }
    }];
}
```

This code works but it`s not good enough. The Node makes huge movements even when i just tap on the device and the overall experience is not very statisfying.
I would like a code that moves the node just by the tilt of the device and not by the x-axis acceleration data. Something like if i tilt the device from 0 to 15 degree nothing happens and after that the node accelerates proportionally in dependency of the devices tilt. And the node should nod make sudden movements but fluent ones. Just like in the Doodle Jump way. I want that exact same behavior. Thanks.

Comment: It would be better to use the physics environment instead of SKActions for the same

Comment: There is an excellent tutorial which describes the same: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-airplane-game-with-sprite-kit-project-setup--mobile-19891